# Autocorrelation function of AR(1)-GARCH(1,1)

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, garch, acf-pacf

How can I derive the Autocorrelation function of AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) process which is the combination of AR(1) with GARCH(1,1) process?

Comment: The ACF of AR(p)-GARCH(s,r) is the same as the ACF of AR(p). The GARCH part does not change anything. See the thread linked above; it considers a more general case of ARMA-GARCH, and your case of AR-GARCH is just a special case of that.